# Building a connection from Eclipse to a PHP database file

Tags: php, android, database, eclipse, wamp

Here is my code for building a connection from Eclipse to a PHP file which contains my database connection, but it stores an empty string to the database. can anyone point out the mistake i may have made along the way?

```
 add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


           public void onClick(View arg0) {
           Intent add = new Intent(addUser.this, FavUser.class);
           startActivity(add);

           InputStream is = null;


           EditText txtSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtSearch);
           String strSearch = txtSearch.getText().toString();

           List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
           nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(strSearch, strSearch));

           try {

               // Add your data

               HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
               HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/connecttodb.php");

               httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

               // Execute HTTP Post Request
               HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
               HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
              is = entity.getContent();

           } catch (IOException e) {
              Log.e("Log_tag", "error in http connection" +e.toString());
           }
           // convert reposonse to string
```

Comment: You'll need to use your computer's IP address rather than `localhost` at the very least.

Comment: check http://fahmirahman.wordpress.com/2011/04/21/connection-between-php-server-and-android-client-using-http-and-json/

Answer (score 0):

The code itself looks good but it would be better if you have provided any error messages. Anyways, I would recommend checking your IP address. It looks like an IP of your router, addressing to your server. Go to google and type in "what is my ip address" and replace it with the one you are using; if it is different. Also do not forget to forward the ports to your server from the router after changing the code.